# How to use Randomize to choose from array list

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, random, basic

I am trying to randomly generate, based off of the 3 array list, 3 different positions the picturebox (stickimage) will appear.

My code so far:

```
    Private Sub GenerateObjects()
    Dim RandomClass As New Random()         'Generate random number
    Dim Y As Integer                        'Y axis
    Dim ObstaclePos(3) As Integer           'Position where obstacle is allocated
    ObstaclePos(1) = 404
    ObstaclePos(2) = 310
    ObstaclePos(3) = 290

    Me.stickImage.Left -= 20


    If stickImage.Bounds.IntersectsWith(LeftStickBrake.Bounds) Then
        For pos = 1 To 3
            Y =                                             'This is where I am stuck
            stickImage.Location = New Point(1014, Y)


        Next pos
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Y = ObstaclePos(RandomClass.Next(1, 4))`

Answer (score 1):

First, review your array declaration.

```
Dim ObstaclePos(3) As Integer
ObstaclePos(1) = 404
ObstaclePos(2) = 310
ObstaclePos(3) = 290
```

You should start from index `0`.

```
Dim ObstaclePos(2) As Integer
ObstaclePos(0) = 404
ObstaclePos(1) = 310
ObstaclePos(2) = 290
```

---

Now you can generate a random index by using [`Random.Next(Integer)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zd1bc8e5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Dim Y As Integer = ObstaclePos(RandomClass.Next(ObstaclePos.Length))
```